# Enterprise Architect - How to create classes from sequence diagrams?

Tags: class, uml, class-diagram, enterprise-architect, sequence-diagram

I have experience with StarUML and Jumli. At my current company we have a Professional license for EA 9.2.
When I design a program, I start with creating Use Cases. Then from every Use Case, I create a Sequence Diagram. And from the Sequence Diagrams, almost every Lifeline-object will become a class (and all messages will become a method). With StarUML and Jumli this wasn't a problem.

But I cannot find a way in EA to convert the Lifeline objects into classes.

[image: My project]

I tried to read the help from Sparx, but to me it is not really helpful. Their 'tutorial' is not a tutorial, but actually just another help file with lots of blah blah.

Can anyone tell me how to do this? Or are there any **really** helpful links?

Comment: In VP-UML you right click on TimeLine, choose "select class"-"create class from timeline" and here you are. Try right click on diagram elements, if repository elements won't help.

Comment: I wish you were right. But I cannot find such an option.

Comment: Alas. I has only demo license and it is over :-(. can't look in EA now. Maybe during the next week.

Comment: I have found it! It is exactly where I have told you - in the popup menu from the diagram itself. Read the answer - there are some conceptual problems you should notice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It IS possible, but only in one a bit hidden way. First I'll tell you about the alternative ways:

- you have a conceptual error here. Timelines in Sequence diagram are not classes, but objects. So, they can't **become** classes.
- Of course, a tool could have a function to create a class according to an object, as VP UML has. Obviously, EA has not such feature.
- On the contrary, it is not a problem to drop a class on the sequence diagram to become a timeline. But EA has some conceptual problems with it, too. You have to make it an object here. [Look also this](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/10/standard_uml_models/sequence_diagrams_and_version_.html).
- On the other hand, there should be no problems to drop a timeline to the object diagram, but in EA it IS a problem - the object-timeline remains the timeline even on the Object diagram. That is obviously non-convenient and ununderstandable, but it is so. Obviously, it is one of these bugs that are called "features".
- The same is behaviour of the timeline if we drop it on the Class Diagram. We even can't connect this object to a class by generalization - EA considers such connection as a rules breaking one.

And finally, how you CAN connect the timeline/object to a class. Right-click the timeline on the sequence diagram or its copy object on the class diagram. Go to Advanced. Choose Instance Classifier - the first menu item. There you can choose an existent class or even create a new one. And the object/timeline will belong to this very class.

You can't reach this feature from the Project Browser. It is obviously, another "feature" of the EA.

Comment: Thanks Gangnus, it is not the answer I had hoped for, but it seems like that is the 'best' way to do it in EA. Thanks for your effort, but next time I think I will not use EA anymore.

Comment: In this way I have to create my classes and methods manually. It looks like EA knows a lot about the theory behind UML, but to me they didn´t succeed to transform that into a practical way of working.

Comment: @ffonz There is no full UML-compliant modelling tool, let alone a CONVENIENT one. IBM modeler is too far from UML standard, VP-UML is extremely bad for free style modelling, and has errors in UML implementation, Visio is not a real modelling tool at all. EA is not worse than them, it is merely worse in some features. Yes, it is less convenient for UML. But don't think other tools are better. For example, there is NO modelling tool in which you can correctly show two different anonymous classes in one container class.

Comment: I have to agree. I am looking for the perfect UML tool now for more then nine years, and I still haven´t found it.

Comment: @ffonz The problem is that very few people really know that UML standard. And the standard is far from being ideal, too. So, a perfect tool wouldn't have its customers.

Answer (score 0):

In a spec-adherent UML tool, one can assign classes (among other things) to a lifeline. I think that is why you are having difficulty converting lifelines into classes: they aren't the same kind of thing! Try creating classes first and assigning them to lifelines.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jim, but to me creating classes first looks more like reverse engineering.

Answer (score 0):

To transform sequence model into class model right-click on the package choose "Transform Current Package" => Check DDL => Select Transform
 I hope this helps.
Regards,
Nabil

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Nabil. It looked promising. But when I tried, it made a mess of it. :-( Everything becomes a table or a column or a primary key. And it does it without any intelligence. Names of Use Cases are turned into tables, which I cannot find any logic for. And I was looking for classes, not tables. I also tried the option 'C#' instead of 'DLL', but then I only get an empty package. But thanks anyway.